# How can I print item[0] from array1 and complete the result from array2 (repeated with item[1])

Tags: c#, arrays

I have these arraies

```
string[] array1 = {"A","A","A","A", "B","B","C","C","C","D"};
int[] array2 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
```

The expected output is:

**A**

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4

**B**

- 5
- 6

and so on.....

I tried this

```
string[] array1 = { "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D" };

int[] array2 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

for (int x = 0; x < array1.Length; x++)
{
    if (array1[x] == array1[x == array1.Length-1? x : x + 1])
    {
        Console.WriteLine(array1[x]);
        Console.WriteLine(array2[x]);
    }
    else
    {
        continue;
    }

}
Console.ReadKey();
```

But doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
for (int x = 0; x < array1.Length; x++)
{
    // display first letter and any letter different from previous one
    if (x == 0 || array1[x] != array1[x - 1])
    {
        Console.WriteLine(array1[x]);
    }
    // in all cases, write the number
    Console.WriteLine(array2[x]);
}
```

Note that when doing this, you should make sure that `array1.Length == array2.Length` or you might end up in trouble.

Comment: When x = 0, the first part of the condition (`x == 0`) is `true`, so the second part is not evaluated (because we use `||`)

Answer (score 1):

Is this a homework assignment or a practical problem you need to solve? If the former, then your classwork may require a solution using only arrays and then [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67785118/3538012) is probably preferred. But if this is a practical problem, then IMHO LINQ would be a better approach, being more expressive of what you actually want to do.

For example:

```cs
string[] array1 = {"A","A","A","A", "B","B","C","C","C","D"};
int[] array2 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
var groups = array1.Zip(array2, (x, y) => (Name: x, Value: y)).GroupBy(t => t.Name);

foreach (var group in groups)
{
    Console.WriteLine(group.Key);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, group.Select(t => t.Value)));
}
```

The above reorganizes the data by combining the corresponding values from each array into a single tuple value, and then uses LINQ to group each value by the name.

Once this is done, outputting the information is as simple as displaying the key for each group, and then displaying all the values within each group.

Comment: No its not a homework, But i need it in some parts of project, I tried this and i got this ``` Name doesnt exist in the current Context ``` i dont know ?

Comment: @Aiman: _"its not a homework"_ -- then IMHO you should prefer this solution, as it is more _expressive_ of the actual operation you're doing. FWIW, it's also more accommodating of different data structures, and in particular doesn't require that the arrays be in any particular order, just that each element corresponds to each other between arrays. Of course, if you are always guaranteed that the data always appears in pre-formed groups, that's fine, but this is not often the case.